# Indexeddb maximum size limit in chromium

Tags: indexeddb, appjs

I'm considering building a LOB appjs application for which I want to use the IndexedDB for storage. I have a few question regarding IndexedDB in appjs.

1. What is the maximum storage limit and is there any way to configure
   appjs' chromium browser to increase the limit?
2. Will I have problems if the data in the IndexedDB exceeds the user's RAM? Since it's just a key value store that stores object graphs, I was wondering if it would load the entire data in RAM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building an application in AppJS then you can skip indexedDB and use an nodejs library to access a full database instead. So for example https://npmjs.org/package/node-sqlite-purejs or https://npmjs.org/package/sqlite3 will give you a full relational database with transactions etc.

If you want to go the nosql route then there are lots of nosql databases available for nodejs. To connect the database to your application in the app.js code you would add a function to the window that can be your database api, so for example it can accept the query name to run or even the sql, then pass in a callback function to call once the data has been run. The function added by app.js to the window object can then query the database and get the records back and then call the callback function with the result.

Comment: I tried sqlite3 but I couldn't get it to work with appjs, it quit with this error `data\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\node_sqlite3.node is not a function`. I got the node-sqlite-purejs library to work, but no ORM supports it, i'd like a higher level interface.

Answer (score 0):

About the storage limit I can't say, but in theory the indexeddb size is limited to the size of your harddisk. But in most cases a limit is set ;).

As far as I know only the data you will be working on will be loaded into memory. JS has it's own garbage collector so that should take care of the RAM usage.